# gameobject is instantiated in the wrong place in game view Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, installation, gameobject, sceneview

[difference between game view and scene view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qS8Nk.jpg)

as you can see from the picture it seems like my game object is being instantiated in the wrong place in my game view while in my scene view it instantiates in the right position anyone can help with this problem ?

***Edit:*** i forgot to say that this only happens to my triple shot
my regular shot works fine

my code for instantiation:

```
 void FireLaser()
    {
         _canFire = Time.time + _fireRate;

        if (_tripleShotEnabled == true)
        {

            Instantiate(_tripleShotPrefab, transform.position , Quaternion.identity);
        }
        else
        {
            Instantiate(_laserPrefab, transform.position + new Vector3(0,1.05F,0), Quaternion.identity);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you using the canvas or multiple cameras?

Comment: I am using only the Main camera

Answer (score 1, accepted):

open the prefab where the bullets are located and and set their position to 0 if you instantiate them

Comment: thanks now i noticed that the location of the children of my prefab were set differently than what i set them initially and after correcting this error every thing works fine now

Answer (score 0):

Open Triple Shot Prefab
See if the positions are wrong
then set the parent "Triple Shot" positions to 0
Try it

Answer (score 0):

It's because when you're dragging the Triple_Shot object from Hierarchy to Project's Prefabs, the laser children's positions got messed up.

Use below:
[image]

Reset the positions to the correct positions when you were initially creating the triple shot prefab. In my case:

Laser has:
[image]

Laser2 has:
[image]

Laser3 has:
[image]

Once you save these changes, then re-simulate the game, the positions of the triple shots will be corrected to the Player's transform.position.